# Not able to sort table view data in ascending order

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an table view which will populate some data. Now I need to sort my table view data in ascending order.

```
var SearchedobjectArray = [Objects]()

struct Objects {
    var looId : String!
    var looName : String
    var looImageUrl:String!
    var looCategoryType:String!
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"cell", for: indexPath) as? MyLooCell{
        cell.looImage.setShowActivityIndicator(true)
        cell.looImage.setIndicatorStyle(.gray)
        let imageURL = SearchedobjectArray[indexPath.row].looImageUrl

        if (imageURL?.isEmpty)! {
            let imageUrl = self.getDefaultImageForCategory(categoryName: SearchedobjectArray[indexPath.row].looCategoryType)
            cell.looImage.image = UIImage(named: imageUrl)
        } else {
            cell.looImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: SearchedobjectArray[indexPath.row].looImageUrl))
        }
        cell.looName.text = SearchedobjectArray[indexPath.row].looName
        let looCatType = SearchedobjectArray[indexPath.row].looCategoryType
    } else {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}
```

I tried with : `let array = SearchedobjectArray.sorted(by: )`

But I am not sure how can I sort this data with ascending order `a to z`. I tried with other `sorted()` also but not able to achieve.

Comment: Share your attempt here please.

Comment: i tried few, but i discard my changes. I tried like `SearchedobjectArray.sorted(by: )`, SearchedobjectArray.sort()`.But  other are like tried with filter sort {$10>$1}`.

Comment: Add your attempts to the question.

Comment: Unrelated but **never** declare struct members as IUO. Remove the exclamation marks or, if you really need optionals, declare them as regular optional (`?`). What is the sort criterium? `name` or `id` or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When data is fetched in an array then you can simply sort the array on looName basis using the following code.

```
SearchedobjectArray = SearchedobjectArray.sorted(by: { $0.looName > $1.looName})
tableView.reloadData()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort your array of objects and then `tableView.reloadData()`.  Here's a Playground example of how to sort your array:

```
import Cocoa

struct Objects {
    var looId : String!
    var looName : String
    var looImageUrl:String!
    var looCategoryType:String!
}

var SearchedobjectArray = [Objects]()

let c = Objects(looId: "Chase", looName: "Chase", looImageUrl: "Chase", looCategoryType: "Chase")
SearchedobjectArray.append(c)

let b = Objects(looId: "Bree", looName: "Bree", looImageUrl: "Bree", looCategoryType: "Bree")
SearchedobjectArray.append(b)

let a = Objects(looId: "Adam", looName: "Adam", looImageUrl: "Adam", looCategoryType: "Adam")
SearchedobjectArray.append(a)

print("Before sorting")
print(SearchedobjectArray)

// The real sorting is happening here...I guessed you wanted to sort by looName
SearchedobjectArray = SearchedobjectArray.sorted(by: { $0.looName < $1.looName })
print("After sorting")
print(SearchedobjectArray)
```